# Using apacite - suppressing in-text initials, but only sometimes!

Tags: apacite

I'm using apacite, but am having a lot of trouble with the document generating in-text initials for references when it shouldn't.

The trouble is, I have both:

1. Different lead authors with the same surname, and
2. Different sources with the same lead author but the names presented differently.

Here are the solutions that I've found, and the issues I've run into with them:

- Apply a blanket suppression to the in-text initials. Unfortunately, this also removes initials when they are legitimately needed e.g. E. McDonald is a different person to C. McDonald.
- Add the name part of the references manually and use the \citeyear function to link it to the reference so that it still appears in the reference list e.g. \citeyear<Clark,>{2018}. This is a nuisance but ultimately works okay for standalone references. However, it is no good for sentence references without parentheses, or when the reference is in the middle of a group (e.g. Adams, 2014; Brown, 2015; H. Clark, 2016; Davis, 2017). As far as I can work out, I can't manually add "Clark" and use the \citeyear function for this source in the middle of the bigger \cite code.
- Change the names in the source bibFile.bib section so that each author is presented in a way that is internally consistent e.g. drop the C so that H. Clark and H. C. Clark appear identical. This means that the record in the reference list doesn't align with the names as published on the original sources. It's perhaps not such a big deal in cases like this where it's just the question of a middle name, but there are other authors with multiple names and where the order, etc, possibly has cultural significance, and I'm very reluctant to start messing with it, as it will end up looking extremely different from the name on the original source documents.

**How can I keep the in-text initials for the references described in type 1 above, but suppress them for the references described in type 2?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: This site thrives on giving precise solutions to well-defined problems. General discussions of broad, abstract questions -- not so much. Please rewrite your posting so that it's centered on a specific, actionable question.

Comment: Hi Mico. My question is "how can I suppress the initials for some in-text references but not others?"